# Append text to JavaFX TextArea during updateProgress

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this simple code below which updates the `TextArea` during `updateProgress`:

```
textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.setEditable(false);
textArea.setFocusTraversable(false);

StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
root.getChildren().add(textArea);

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 350);

primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Concurrency");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

task = new Task<Integer>(){
    @Override
    protected Integer call() throws Exception {
        int i;
        for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
            updateProgress(i, 100);
        }
        return i;
    }
};
task.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>(){
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> observable, State oldValue, State state) {
        System.out.println(state);
    }
});
task.progressProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>(){
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number val) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textArea.appendText("Value : " + val.intValue() + "\n");
            }
        });
    }
});
new Thread(task).start();
```

But unfortunately the result was wrong. Here's the output:

[image]

I was expecting that the output should be **Value : 1 to Value : 100.**.

I was just trying to test the concurrency package in JavaFX. Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried to change that `textArea.setEditable(false);` by that `textArea.setEditable(true);`  ?

Comment: @Mxsky, whats the point?

Comment: From the doc:  "Sets or indicates whether the user can edit the text in the text field."

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894366/how-to-update-textareaconsolein-realtime-in-javafx-without-loosing-flow-or-fre/33919485#33919485)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insert a simple:

```
Thread.sleep(10);
```

after you call `updateProgress(i, 100);`, everything will be better.
This comes from the documentation of [`updateProgress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress%28double,%20double%29):

> Calls to updateProgress are coalesced and run later on the FX application thread, and calls to updateProgress, even from the FX Application thread, may not necessarily result in immediate updates to these properties, and intermediate workDone values may be coalesced to save on event notifications. max becomes the new value for totalWork.

After this you can experience that more text-lines are appended to your text box, but:

**This does not ensure that all of your updates will be done on your textbox!**

If you want to ensure this, call the GUI update directly in the `call()` of task wrapped in the `Platform.runlater(...)` block.